# xcode invalid archive in organizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, archive

i get message during archive validation. i've tried most of solutions from other questions. but still failed. (It was ok when i submit it last time in xcode 4.02, then i get rejected. i edited some image and .m file(not project settings).

my project Build settings:
 Architectures->standard (armv7) - $(ARCH_STANDARD_32_BIT) 
 Base sdk->Latest ios(ios 5.0)
 valid Architectures armv6 armv7 arvm7f armv7k
 Build active architecture only->no
 ios deployment target: ios3.0

1. i've tried reinstalling xcode and make sure unix is checked, 5 times.
2. i've tried install back  to xcode 4.02, but the same message as xcode 4.2
3. i've tried reinstall cocos2d
4. i've tried to set the llvm/gcc to gcc only

warning message 1: 
    Project Clean-Up Outdated settings should be updated. 
when i click it. one is to set gcc to llve-gcc, another is to 'Enable compiler warning for missing Function Prototypes. ' I clicked cancel

warning message 2:

```
Check dependencies

[BWARN]warning: iPhone apps with a deployment target lower than 4.3 should include an armv6 architecture (current IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = "4.1", ARCHS = "armv7").
```

warning 3:

```
Validate /Users/lifesucks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FishvsBirdsLite-frctqlpldaogcjebgvxkvvmsehie/ArchiveIntermediates/FishvsBirdsLite/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FishvsBirdsLite.app
cd "/Users/lifesucks/my app/Fish vs Birds/FishvsBirdsLite"
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/lifesucks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FishvsBirdsLite-frctqlpldaogcjebgvxkvvmsehie/ArchiveIntermediates/FishvsBirdsLite/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FishvsBirdsLite.app

2011-06-14 01:30:10.948 Validation[8609:607] *** Warning: Defaulting to the standard codesign tool
warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6 (-19033)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

warning: There is no codesign_wrapper executable. Please reinstall the Xcode developer tools. (-19058)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)
```

the error message in organizer is:

the archive is invalid. /var/folders/H5/.../app.ipa does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually don't know why, but it works now. I reinstall back to xcode 4.0.2. then recreated a project, copied over all my classes. i assume that the problem is 'Architectures->standard (armv7)', in xcode 4.0.2 the Architectures is standard armv6/armv7, maybe it's because of cocos2d compatibility to the new version i don't know. anyway if you encounter the same problem, just install back to non-beta and create a new project (since the original setting of 'Architecture' will be modified to 'armv7 standard'. ) hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I updated to Xcode 4.2.  I went back to the latest non-Beta Xcode version to fix it.  The key is, when uninstalling Xcode, you *must* do it via the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

This takes a few minutes.  But when it's done, install the non-Beta Xcode (4.0.2 at this time), and then RESTART before using it.  Worked for me.

Comment: i've tried reinstalling to xcode 4.02(without mode = all) and reinstalling to xcode 4.2(with mode = all). not sure if i need to do it (install to 4.02 and mode = all)

Comment: Uninstall both versions via the command above (or whatever version is currently on your machine if only 1).  Then install 4.0.2. Then restart, archive, and submit.  Let us know if that works. Hope it does.

Comment: nope, the first one has mode = all, so it's not the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Remove iphoneossimulator from supported platforms for the distribution/release build configuration. That is if you have it.
You cannot have that for distribution, it is only for your debug configurations.

Check the image below for distribution configuration (ignore release config).

[image]

Comment: nope. my game is released and the supported platform is debug: simulator, release: simulator and no distribution key. i think archiving by organizer config it for you automatically